# Target OS implementation

Tags: c++, c

I was able to make an implementation to detect the OS.
I'm not sure if it works the way it should, so I asked this question

**TargetOS.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef TARGET_OS_HPP
#define TARGET_OS_HPP
#if defined(__unix__) \
    || defined(linux) \
    || defined(__unix) \
    || defined(__linux__) \
    || defined(__APPLE__) \
    || defined(__MACH__) \
    || defined(__ANDROID__) \
    || defined(__MINGW32__) \
    || defined(__MINGW64__) \
    || defined(__GNUC__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define SPM_UNIX_
#elif defined(WIN32) \
    || defined(_WIN32) \
    || defined(_WIN64) \
    || defined(__NT__) \
    && !defined(__MINGW32__) && !defined(__MINGW64__) \
    && !defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define SPM_WINDOWS_

#else
    #define SPM_UP_ // UP - unknown platform.
#endif

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
    #define SPM_MINGW_
#elif defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define SPM_CYGWIN
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
    #define SPM_ANDROID_
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__) // From https://github.com/mstg/iOS-full-sdk/blob/master/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/include/TargetConditionals.h
    #include <TargetConditionals.h>

    #if defined(TARGET_OS_MAC)      // - Generated code will run under Mac OS X variant

        #if defined(TARGET_OS_IPHONE)   // - Generated code for firmware, devices, or simulator 



            #if defined(TARGET_OS_IOS_) \
                || defined(TARGET_OS_WATCH) \
                || defined(TARGET_OS_TV)    
                #define SPM_MAC_IWT // IWT - IOS, WATCH, TV
            #endif

        #elif defined(TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR)    //  - Generated code will run under a simulator
            #define SPM_MAC_IWT_SIMULATOR

        #elif defined(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)  // - DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
            #define SPM_MAC_IWT_SIMULATOR

        #elif defined(TARGET_OS_NANO) // DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_WATCH
            #define SPM_MAC_IWT

        #else 
            #error "Unknown Mac Platform"
        #endif 
    #endif // defined(TARGET_OS_MAC)
#endif // defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
#endif // TARGET_OS_HPP
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We review working code. The statement `I'm not sure if it works the way it should, so I asked this question.` could make this question off-topic for this site. Have you tested the code and does it seem to work as expected? Please read [How do I ask a good question](I'm not sure if it works the way it should, so I asked this question).

Comment: There's at least one syntax eror in the code (the continuation of `#elif defined(WIN32)` is missing). Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code works.

Comment: @pacmaninbw this is standard Mac file.

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted by a compiler, because escaped newlines are removed (line splicing) before comments are removed (by replacing by a space).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I am on Linix, and I haven't got Windows and Mac. I am new to c ++ and not sure if this works correctly on other platforms, so I ask for a review from other, more experienced developers

Comment: After the edit this question is on topic. It has been tested to the best of the posters ability to test.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you test for `SPM_UNIX_` first.

That test includes test for the value of:

```
    || defined(__MINGW32__) \
    || defined(__MINGW64__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
```

If any of these are true then you have a SPM_UNIX

Which means that these tests:

```
    && !defined(__MINGW32__) && !defined(__MINGW64__) \
    && !defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(__CYGWIN32__)
```

Are superfluous as this will never be reached if any of the above is true.

In:

```
#if defined(__unix__) \
    || defined(linux) \
    || defined(__unix) \
    || defined(__linux__) \
    || defined(__APPLE__) \
    || defined(__MACH__) \
    || defined(__ANDROID__) \
    || defined(__MINGW32__) \
    || defined(__MINGW64__) \
    || defined(__GNUC__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN__) \
    || defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define SPM_UNIX_
#elif defined(WIN32) \
    || defined(_WIN32) \
    || defined(_WIN64) \
    || defined(__NT__) \
    && !defined(__MINGW32__) && !defined(__MINGW64__) \
    && !defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(__CYGWIN32__)
    #define SPM_WINDOWS_

#else
    #define SPM_UP_ // UP - unknown platform.
#endif
```

---